# How to adjust object rotation based on player direction?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm trying to create a 2D top-down shooter. I want to setup a way for the player to hold the gun in the direction of the which he is moving in. For example, if the player is holding the W and A keys, his gun point in the top right direction. As he switches between directions, the gun also switches smoothly. If the player is going up at a straight angle (Ex. Holding W key), the whole player switches direction.

I have managed to replicate this but only in 6 directions. However, I want to make it smooth with the player movement and in all other directions.
I know there has to be a simple answer to this, I just can't figure it out. Here is my code, the functions are named after their purpose:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Character Attributes:")]
    public float movementBaseSpeed = 1.0f;

    [Space]
    [Header("Weapon Statistics:")]
    public float upwardSideAngle = 30f;
    public float downwardSideAngle = -30f;
    public float idleAngle = -10f;

    [Space]
    [Header("Character Statistics:")]
    public Vector2 currentMovementDirection;
    public float currentMovementSpeed;

    [Space]
    [Header("References:")]
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Animator animator;
    public GameObject weapon;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        ProcessInputs();
        Move();
        Animate();
        MoveAim();
    }

    void ProcessInputs()
    {
        currentMovementDirection = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        currentMovementSpeed = Mathf.Clamp(currentMovementDirection.magnitude, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        currentMovementDirection.Normalize();
    }

    void Animate()
    {
        if (currentMovementDirection != Vector2.zero)
        {
            animator.SetFloat("Horizontal", currentMovementDirection.x);
            animator.SetFloat("Vertical", currentMovementDirection.y);
        }
        animator.SetFloat("Magnitude", currentMovementDirection.magnitude);
    }

    void Move()
    {
        rb.velocity = currentMovementDirection * currentMovementSpeed * movementBaseSpeed;
    }

    void MoveAim()
    {
        //When player is moving left
        if(currentMovementDirection.x < 0)
        {
            weapon.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0);
        }
        //When player is moving right
        else if(currentMovementDirection.x > 0)
        {
            weapon.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
        }
        //When player is moving top right
        if(currentMovementDirection.y > 0 && currentMovementDirection.x > 0)
        {
            weapon.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, upwardSideAngle);
        }
        //When player is moving bottom right
        if(currentMovementDirection.y < 0 && currentMovementDirection.x > 0)
        {
            weapon.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, downwardSideAngle);
        }
        //When player is moving top left
        if(currentMovementDirection.y > 0 && currentMovementDirection.x < 0)
        {
            weapon.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, upwardSideAngle);
        }
        //When player is moving bottom left
        if (currentMovementDirection.y < 0 && currentMovementDirection.x < 0)
        {
            weapon.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, downwardSideAngle);
        }
        //When player is standing still
        if (currentMovementDirection.y == 0 && currentMovementDirection.x == 0)
        {
            weapon.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, idleAngle);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of describing what you want is that you want the gun's local `right` to point in the direction you're moving while it's local `up` is as close to `Vector3.up` as possible. (You can use Vector3 and Vector2 interchangeably for math purposes.)

If you can solve for the direction you want the gun transform's forward and up to be, you can use [`Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3 forwardDirection, Vector3 upDirection)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) to calculate the rotation for the gun transform.

Here's a way you can use vector math to solve for the directions and use `Quaternion.LookRotation` to assign the rotation.

```
void MoveAim()
{
    Vector3 gunRight = currentMovementDirection;
    Vector3 gunForward = Vector3.Cross(gunRight, Vector3.up);
    // Handle cases where the gun is pointing directly up or down
    if (gunForward == Vector3.zero)
    {
        gunForward = Vector3.forward;
    }

    Vector3 gunUp = Vector3.Cross(gunForward, gunRight);

    weapon.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(gunForward, gunUp);

    //When player is standing still
    if (currentMovementDirection == Vector2.zero)
    {
        weapon.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, idleAngle);
    }
}
```